# detecting right mouse click with Bing maps

Tags: bing-maps

I am trying to capture a right mouse click on a Bing map.  All I get is the browser context menu (which I want to disable).  How do I modify the following code to make the right mouse click work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var map = null;

        function GetMap() {
            // Initialize the map
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"),
                         { credentials: "MyApiKey" });

            //Add handler for the map click event.
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', function (e) {
                alert('click');
                if (e.isSecondary)
                    alert('rightclick');
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
    <div id='myMap'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using v7, there is a [rightclick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427609.aspx) Event on the Map you can register with:

```
   Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'rightclick', function(e) {
        alert('click');
        if (e.isSecondary)
            alert('rightclick');
    });
```

To disable the browser context menu, that question is already answered here:

[Bing Maps V7 Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648694/bing-maps-v7-context-menu)

with the relevant parts re-pasted below:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
...
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I don't see an event for right double click.  How would I capture that?

Comment: Try the dblclick event and interrogate the isSecondary Property on MouseEventArgs.  I haven't tried it but it might work.

Comment: Y, I tried that, but it didn't work.  If I find the answer I will update this post.  Thx!